# How to access Google OAuth RefreshToken and AccessToken without saving them in session cookie?

Tags: haskell, google-oauth, yesod

In Yesod, how does one get access to, both, the Google OAuth access token and refresh token without storing them in the session cookie (as it is mentioned here -- https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-6.7/yesod-auth-1.4.13.3/Yesod-Auth-GoogleEmail2.html#g:2 )

If I'm using `authGoogleEmail` instead of `authGoogleEmailSaveToken`, how can I access the access AND refresh token?

Comment: Looking at the source code, it seems it is not storing `refresh_token` in both cases.

Comment: That was my analysis as well. However, I'm not really interested in storing the tokens in the session cookie. I need to access them to store them in the DB, **especially** the `refresh_token`